What is the difference between using ; and && in package.json scripts?
What is the difference between using ; and && in package.json scripts?
For example the Lit Element Typescript Starter Project has this script:
"checksize": "rollup -c ; cat my-element.bundled.js | gzip -9 | wc -c ; rm my-element.bundled.js"
  },

What effect does the ; have?

That's actually shellscript that's being executed and has nothing to do with javascript.
Difference here between && and ; is the failure tolerance:
command1 ; command2
If command1 fails, command2 will still be executed.
command1 && command2
Here if command1 fails, command2 will not be executed.
